# Does Python also has some inbuilt data sets like R to perform tests upon?

Tags: python, r

To perform basic operations like data manipulation does python also has some inbuilt or by default data to work upon as in R programming language ? If yes , then how to access them ?

Answer (score 3):

sklearn library has some good datasets
You can view the list with the following, after downloading sklearn:

```
from sklearn import datasets
dir(datasets)
```